# Is it possible to auto generate nice documentation for REST API created by ServiceStack?

Tags: rest, documentation-generation, servicestack

There are existing tools for auto generating API documentation - most of the weren't designed for REST services.

For all of you who have created REST services using ServiceStack - how did you write the docs ?
Manual / semi-auto / fully auto-gen ?
I'm even considering auto gen a customized WADL and connecting it to something like apigee [Console To Go](http://apigee.com/docs/consoletogo)

(oh and RESTafaries- please spare the 'REST api should be auto discoverable and self-explained' mantra...I really want nice looking docs for my users).

Comment: Hi Froyke. Please refer to my comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/22939360/214747 for the recommended way to document ServiceStack Web Services.

Comment: Thanks but that is no so visually appealing and not so user-friendly. At the end of the day I have (manually) created a WADL file that is transformed using XSLT to a nice HTML. See it in action here: http://developer.dome9.com/reference.html I also like Apigee's console so the same WADL file can feed their console: https://apigee.com/froyke/embed/console/dome9

Answer (score 1):

Documenting an API through XHTML might provide better results than formatting DTO's. Look at http://www.amundsen.com/blog/archives/1043 and this inspiring [video](https://vimeo.com/20781278).