# Is there a razor template for ServiceStacks metadata page

Tags: servicestack

I've 20+ operations now and will soon double that. Without some kind of grouping the metadata page isn't very useful. I want to add some simple grouping by routing addresses. As it's a RESTful API it would be good group it by folder structure. If there was a Razor view for the default one, changing it to group or some other way would be easy.

The XSD doesn't have routing addresses in it either.

I looked at this but it seems to be just about links on the page: [Is it possible to customize the ServiceStack /metadata page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344149/is-it-possible-to-customize-the-servicestack-metadata-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a [ServiceStack metadata](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Metadata-page) razor page that you can change, but there is a [Swagger API for ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API) and the built-in [Metadata feature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/MetadataFeature.cs) is just a [Plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Plugins) so you can easily remove it at which point you're free to add your own customized metadata pages.

It it helps, you can start from a copy of the [Metadata pages](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/MetadataFeature.cs).

Comment: For now I'm leaving it as is. Swagger looks interesting for later but that level of documentation is a low priority. I was looking for some low hanging fruit regarding documentation.

Comment: Turns out the Swagger plugin is very simple to get up and running and automatically groups by path out of the box.